# How to delete tr row from table with modal dialog using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap along with the jQuery plugins it comes with on a small project.  Right now I have a modal dialog popping up for deletion confirmation, and when the user clicks the confirm button it deletes the record just fine.

However, what I also want to do is have the table row that had the button it was clicked on to be removed as well.  So, if the user clicks on the "Delete" button on tr row 5, when the user confirms it'll remove tr row 5 as well from the table.

The table is generated dynamically but here's a small example:

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" style="table-layout: fixed;" id="api_key_list">
<tbody>
<tr id="key_0"><td>test</td>
<td>eqeI0Tt-V7rzijDfLqrna2</td>
<td>eqeI0Tt-V7rzijDfLqrn</td>
<td>
<input type="hidden" id="api_server_31" value="test" />
<input type="hidden" id="api_server_31_sid" value="null" />
<input type="hidden" id="api_server_31_tid" value="0" />
<button type="submit" class="api_key_edit btn btn-small btn-primary" value="31">Edit</button>
<button type="submit" class="api_key_delete btn btn-small btn-danger" value="31">Delete</button>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My dialog is also dynamically generated but here's what it shows for this example:

```html
<div id="api_key_delete" class="modal hide fade in" role="dialog" style="display: block;" aria-hidden="false"><div class="modal-header"><button class="close" aria="hidden="true"" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"> … </button><h3 id="label">
      Delete API Key for 
    <span id="api_key_delete_server">
      test
    </span>
      ?
    </h3></div><div class="modal-body"> … </div><div class="modal-footer"> … </div></div>
```

My JS code is this:

```js
$("#conf_delete").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($(this).hasClass("disabled")){
        return false;
    }

    var conf = $("#conf_delete").val();
    conf = conf.split("|");

    var server = conf[0];
    var kid = conf[1];
    var tid = conf[2].substring(4);

    $.post("/api",
        {server : server, id : kid, api_act : "deletek"},
        function(data){
            var n = data.split("|");
            var type = n[0];
            var msg = n[1];
            var dak = $("#delete_api_key_msgbox");

            dak.show();

            if(type == "e"){
                dak.addClass("alert-error");
            } else{
                dak.addClass("alert-success");

                $("#conf_delete").addClass("disabled");

                $("#api_key_delete").modal("hide");
                // issue is here, though tr is captured, the fadeout/remove doesn't work
                var tr = $("#api_server_"+server).closest("tr");
                console.log("tr:"+tr);
                tr.fadeOut(400, function(){
                    tr.remove();
                });
            }

            $("#dak_msg").html(msg);
        }
    );
});
```

What happens is that the dialog pops up, user clicks confirm and the dialog shows the message, but it doesn't seem to do anything to the background no matter where I place the fadeOut/remove code.

Comment: Are you sure you are capturing the correct `tr`? I dumbed down your javascript and the `fadeOut` appears to be working. What version of jQuery are you using? http://jsfiddle.net/mikeyfreake/357hG/

Comment: Yeah; it works when its not being done from the dialog.  I can even do it in the JavaScript console in Firefox and it works fine.  Its just when the code is run from the click event of the dialog itself it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Are you able to setup a fiddle that shows the problem? I know this can get a bit hard to model when ajax calls are involved - or maybe it's just me who is unsure how to model ajax calls in JSFiddle.

Comment: Best I can do: http://jsfiddle.net/GP6tW/5/

Dialog doesn't show up though in this and I think its because it can't load the JS files.

Comment: Updated the fiddle so the JS and CSS work: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeyfreake/jKwn8/1/

Comment: Hm...  I updated it to this: http://jsfiddle.net/jKwn8/9/ and it worked then.  Maybe its not catching the ```server``` variable and thus not continuing, but the console.log() output shows it as an object.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong variable.  This is quite embarassing.